# How to delegate the implementation of one class in other class in Java?

Tags: java, delegation

I am trying to refactor util java class A(for example). It is composed of all static methods, but there are a lot of methods so i extracted few methods which are independent of each other and created a helper class B(Code Quality Analysis tool complains of having too any methods in this class) Now, I don't know how to make class B backward compatible? 
I have been asked to create a "method" in Class A and delegate the implementation of Class B in it. I don't understand how that can be done. 
I know we can achieve delegation through interfaces, and other design patterns in java. But these classes are really not complicated.

So how can this be done by creating a method?

```
    public class A{
    public static doSomething1();
    public static doSomething2();
    public static doSomething3();

    }

    public class B{
    public static doSomethingElse1();
    public static doSomethingElse2();
    public static doSomethingElse3();

    }
```

Comment: Since we are talking about `static` utility methods, the best you can do is probably invoke `B`'s method from `A`'s method body, although you might end up wanting to rethink the design.

Comment: delegation alone will not reduce the number of methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called the adapter pattern, and it is pretty simple. Create a method in class `A`:

```
class A {
    ...
    public static doSomethingElse1() {
        B.doSomethingElse1();
    }
}
```

Which simply calls the same method in class `B`.

Although this answers your question, it will not help you much. The best course of action would be to try and completely remove these utility classes, going for a more OO design, but without more details, it hard to say if that is possible.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought it means but you are right it would not help because I will end up having same number of methods. I will have to move towards another design. Thanks very much!